# Python: unnest json array without key

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a json array, but I'm stuck with getting it unnested nicely.

So the Json Array is like this:

```
{'availability': 
   {'2022-07-15': [{'id': '1234', 'quantity': 14}, {'id': '5678', 'quantity': 18}, {'id': '2345', 'quantity': 20}], 
    '2022-07-17': [{'id': '1234', 'quantity': 2}, {'id': '5678', 'quantity': 74}, {'id': '2345', 'quantity': 64}]}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
             id      quantity
2022-07-15   1234     14
2022-07-15   5678     18
2022-07-15   2345     20
2022-07-17   1234     2
2022-07-17   5678     74
2022-07-17   2345     64
```

But I seem to get stuck at the 'availability' part. I tried to use

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['id']. meta=['quantity']
```

But it meantions that the key 'id' could not be found. It seems like 'availability' is one key, but the date doesn't seem to be. Could someone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: That above is not JSON, so it's hard to say how to treat it. Can you please extract a [mcve] that not just shows a representative extract of the data but also of the code you tried? Also, if you're using Pandas, add that to the tags.

Comment: Hmm, this is the output from an api, just truncated to two rows, as it continues the same until the end of the month. If I use an online JSON parser, I get the unnested structure.

Comment: Which online JSON parser is that? Point is, the above is not JSON. Check out json.org, you can quickly see that the string-like things above are not JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dct` is the dictionary from the question, you can do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    ({"index": k, **d} for k, l in dct["availability"].items() for d in l),
).set_index("index")
df.index.name = None

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              id  quantity
2022-07-15  1234        14
2022-07-15  5678        18
2022-07-15  2345        20
2022-07-17  1234         2
2022-07-17  5678        74
2022-07-17  2345        64
```

Comment: Awesome, this works just as I want. So if I understand correctly, what you did was look for the index position of k, just before the key that ends with d (which would be id), and then set it as index?

Comment: @Masterclown `{"index": k, **d}` will create a dictionary with key `index` and value in `k` and all keys/values from dictionary `d`